# Why do I get a different answer using math.fmod vs mod operator (positive integers only)

Tags: python, integer-division, modulo

Trying to find the smallest positive integer n such that n! divided by the sum of the digits of n! has a remainder.

Two people approached the problem in similar ways but got different answers. I've read that % and fmod behave differently with negative numbers but there are no negative numbers involved here. Large number calculators online seem to show that the solution arrived at through % is correct.

Using mod operator:

```
import math
n=1
def func():
    global n
    intn=[]
    
#for loop creates a list of integers of the digits of n!
    for digit in str(math.factorial(n)):
         intn.append(int(digit))
    denominator=sum(intn)
    
#if n!/denominator has a remainder, print n; the program is over. Otherwise, increase n and try again.
    if (math.factorial(n))%denominator:
        print(n)
    else:
        n+=1
        func()
func()
```

Changing `if (math.factorial(n))%(denominator):` to `if int((math.factorial(n)))%int(denominator):` changed the result so that it is the same as when using .fmod, but again, I don't think that is the correct answer.

Using math.fmod:

```
import math

# curNum is the variable I'm using to track the integer whose value I'm testing
curNum = 1

# conditionMet is a boolean that will be used to break the while loop of the test
conditionMet = False


while conditionMet == False:
    sumDigits = 0
    curFactorial = math.factorial(curNum)
    curFactorialAsString = str(curFactorial)
    #sumDigits  = sum(int(curNumAsString))
    for curDigit in curFactorialAsString:
            sumDigits = sumDigits + int(curDigit)
    if math.fmod(curFactorial,sumDigits) != 0:
        print("curNum: " + str(curNum) + "curFactorial: " + str(curFactorial) + "sumDigits: " + str(sumDigits))
        conditionMet = true
    else:
        curNum = curNum + 1
```

Comment: `math.fmod` operates on floating point values, so you're probably running into precision issues because factorials get pretty large pretty quickly.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fmod) explains how `fmod` differs from `%`, provides an example where floating-point imprecision causes a problem, and recommends using `fmod` for floats and `%` for ints.

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation and updating your question if you have a specific question about what it says; otherwise, an answer to this question is just going to be a regurgitation of the documentation (which is only a paragraph long and not difficult to follow).

Comment: @Thomas Everything I'm reading about floating point precision only talks about it being an issue for numbers smaller than 1, so just to make sure I'm understanding correctly, are you suggesting that factorial numbers get large enough that the 53 bits of a floating point number are not enough to store them, which in turn messes with the division?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Above 53 bits, you start losing precision _before_ the decimal point, so the modulo won't be exact anymore.